# Using AutoFileName with Sublime Text 2

Tags: editor, sublimetext2

I have installed the package 'AutoFileName' but when I try to define an img source I recieve only tag options and not images. Does anyone know if I have to define the folder where my images are or where AutoFileName looks for images?

Comment: `AutoFileName` list files based on the html file you edit. For example, if `test1.img`, `test2.img` and `test.html` are in the same folder, it will list `test1.img` and `test2.img` if you are trying to add `<img src="">` in `test.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AutoFileName` lists files based on the html file you edit. For example, if `test1.img`, `test2.img` and `test.html` are in the same folder, it will list `test1.img` and `test2.img` if you are trying to add `<img src="">` in test.html.